# What is reduced modulo 32 or 64?

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation

In the Core Java Volume1 book there is a caution that say:

> CAUTION: The right-hand side argument of the shift operators is reduced modulo 32 
>   (unless the left-hand side is a long, in which case the right-hand side is reduced modulo 64). 
>   For example, the value of 1 << 35 is the same as 1 << 3 or 8.

What exactly does this mean? also why 1 become 8, instead of being 0 after 35 left shifting?

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many programming languages, shifting by more than the size of a numeric data type (32 bits for an int, 64 bits for a long) is undefined.  On the other hand, Java defines it such that `(n << d)` is equivalent to `(n << (d % 32))` where `n` is an int, and `(n << d)` is equivalent to `(n << (d % 64))` where `n` is a long.

So, `1 << 35` is equivalent to `1 << (35 % 32)`, which equals `1 << 3 = 8`.

Answer (score 13):

Reduced modulo 32 means (at its base level) you keep subtracting 32 until you have a number between 0 and 31 inclusive.

In other words:

```
actualValue = givenValue % 32;
```

The *reason* it does this is because it makes little sense to shift a 32-bit value 32 bits to the left (or right) since it will *always* be zero (because you're shifting bits out on one side and shifting zeros *in* on the other side - doing that 32 times to a 32-bit value is going to result in zero no matter what you started with).

So for Java integers (32-bit), 31 is the sensible limit. For longs (64-bit), 63 is the sensible limit.

In the example you give, `1 << 35` has the shift value reduced from 35 to 3 (since `35 % 32 == 3`) and 1 << 3 is 8:

```
 Binary
0000 0001    (1 << 0) == 1
0000 0010    (1 << 1) == 2
0000 0100    (1 << 2) == 4
0000 1000    (1 << 3) == 8
     ||||
     |||+--- 1
     ||+---- 2
     |+----- 4
     +------ 8
```

Comment: For more information, the language reference: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19

Answer (score 4):

More succinctly

```
a << b
```

is the same as

```
a << (b & 31)
```

for int types.

The difference is that -1 % 32 is -1 whereas -1 & 31 is 31 and `1 << -1 == 0x80000000`

This behaviour is defined in [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

Comment: @mug896 It is defined in the JLS. Updated my answer.